# Remove &quot; when printing an array in the JavaScript console

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have an array that I am passing to a javascript file.

In the controller I have the array printing out and it appears like so...

```
["123456789", "987654321", "147852369", "369852147"]
```

This array is set to the instance variable @array in the controller.

I'm sending this array to a JavaScript file by setting `@array` as a variable in the view.

```
var array = "<%= @array %>";
```

*Note: I've tried `var array = "<%=raw @array.to_json %>";` as well.*

Then in the JavaScript file I am simply printing the array in the console like so...

```
console.log(array);
```

However when it is printed in the console the output looks like this.

```
[&quot;123456789&quot;, &quot;987654321&quot;, &quot;147852369&quot;, &quot;369852147&quot;]
```

When I check the typeof through jQuery it comes back as a string instead of an array.

I do not want to see the `&quot;`. Eventually I want to use these values as selectors when running some JavaScript functions.

Through these steps, what am I doing wrong that is producing the `&quot;`?

edit: This is how I am initially creating my array.

```
  CONTROLLER
  @original= large_array_of_hashes
  # I am grabbing only specific data from the hash. Only what comes after @errors=>
  @data = @original.scan(/@errors=>"(.*?)"/).flatten.map{ |msg| msg.gsub(/(\.|\s+)/, '').strip }
  @array = []
  @data.each{|data| @array << data}
```

Comment: Try `<%=raw @array.to_json.html_safe %>`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work... I got an `SyntaxError: Unexpected number` error

Comment: TRy this `<%= @array.to_json.flatten.to_json.html_safe %>` or just `<%= raw @array %>`

Comment: The first option gave me an `internal server error` and the second method gave me the same `SyntaxError: Unexpected number` .... I've updated my question to include how I am creating my array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TRy this, place them in single quotes

IN javascript

```
var array = '<%= @array.to_json %>';
array.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
```

Comment: The first option does not seem to like the .flatten `undefined method flatten`

Comment: Ok I thought that looked a little strange haha. I tried the update as well as the second option and got the same `SyntaxError: Unexpected number` error :(

Comment: try removing `&quotes` by using `gsub` `@array.gsub('"', '&quot;')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73372/discussion-between-mikeymurph77-and-sontya).

Answer (score 4):

My issue was corrected by just prepending raw to my ruby variable

```
<%= raw @array %>
```

I know it's late but hope it helps someone down the road!

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
@array = %w[123456789 987654321 147852369 369852147]
```

and then your javascript things will work.